# Typescript/React extending default functional component props gives error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

For the death of me I cannot figure this out for the past three hours and I am very frustrated so I apologize in advance if I sound a big aggressive.

All I want is to be able to define a typescript interface for my component and have it extend the default interface any component uses, to avoid having to declare every goddamn default prop such as `className`, `onClick` and the like in my own interface.

I have this component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, FunctionComponent } from 'react'
import './style.scss'

interface ISideProps {
  wideModeEnabled: boolean
  toggleWideMode
  setFocus
}

const AppLayoutSide: FunctionComponent<ISideProps> = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef() as any
  ...
  ...
  etc.
  return <div {...props} />
}
```

Now there is no error in this component, at least typescript doesn't give any. But if I try to render this component in another one, for example like this:

```
const otherComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className='content'>
      <Menu />
      <Main />
      <Side
        className={'whatever'}  //Typescript error happens here
        wideModeEnabled={wideMode}
        toggleWideMode={toggleWideMode}
        setFocus={setSideFocus}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

And the error says:

> Type '{ className: string; wideModeEnabled: boolean; toggleWideMode:
> () => void; setFocus: Dispatch<SetStateAction>; }' is not
> assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ISideProps & { children?:
> ReactNode; }'.

> Property 'className' does not exist on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & ISideProps & { children?: ReactNode;
> }'.ts(2322)

Which is obviously true, I've not defined className on `ISideProps` interface, but I want to extend the default react props goddamn it! And no matter what I've tried I cannot seem to get it to work. Every guide online keeps suggesting to add `: FunctionalComponent<ISideProps>` to the component declaration, and I did, but it doesn't solve a thing.

Help please, I am losing my mind.

Comment: Might benefit you just to use Javascript, Typescript is nice and all but static typing really doesn't provide any reduced bug benefit, you can just rename something easier. I have found with NodeJS that using Typescript can just be an unneeded pain. I have never seen someone use Typescript with React before

Comment: I could not imagine using react without typescript. JS is a pure mess without autocomplete and unexpected run time errors. Reminds me of jQuery days. TS is sometimes verbose but definetely worth the effort.

Comment: Couldn't disagree more, it makes my life a living hell and I wish it was never invented. JS on the other hand is amazing and I can understand the need for TS before the whole decorators/modules/es6. But now? It is just horrible. Opinions, right? :S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Using `type` (Personal preference)**

After working years with react and typescript I prefer using `type` instead of `interface` for defining props:

```
// Can use any other html tag instead of "th"
type CustomThProps = JSX.IntrinsicElements["th"] & {
  otherProp: string;
}

const CustomTh = ({ otherProp, children, ...rest }: CustomThProps) => {
  return ( 
    <th {...rest}>{ children } </th>
}
```

Using `JSX.IntrinsicElements` unfortunately only works with `type` and not `interface`.
The reason why I like this approach the most is because you can conveniently use the html tag instead of having to know that `th` translates to `HTMLTableHeaderCellElement` in JSX.

With `forwardRef`:

```
// Can use any other html tag instead of "th"
type CustomThProps = JSX.IntrinsicElements["th"] & {
  otherProp: string;
}

const CustomTh = React.forwardRef<React.ElementRef<"th">, CustomThProps>(({ otherProp, children, ...rest }, ref) => {
  return ( 
    <th ref={ref] {...rest}>{ children } </th>
    )

})
```

**Using `interface` (OLD ANSWER)**

If you want to use interfaces `HTMLProps<T>` seems like the most reliable and universal compared to `HTMLAttributes<T>`.

For example, when you want to extend props for a `<th>`-element.
You can no longer use `HTMLAttributes<T>`, instead you have to use `ThHTMLAttributes<T>`:

```
interface IProps extends React.ThHTMLAttributes<HTMLTableHeaderCellElement>
{
...
}
```

With `HTMLProps<T>` you can always use the same signature:

```
interface IProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLTableHeaderCellElement>
{
...
}
```

**Using `interface` (OLD ANSWER)**

Extend your props from react's in-built interface and destructure your props like so:

```
interface ISideProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
{
...
}

const AppLayoutSide = (props: ISideProps) => { 
const { wideModeEnabled,  toggleWideMode, setFocus, ...rest } = props;

return (<div {...rest}></div>)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, changed in the original post, but still doesn't solve the error though

Comment: The problem is not in the props here, its within the other component where I pass it the `className`. Using `<div {...props}>` works just fine, in terms of passing the props, problem lies in GETTING the `className` in the props, because it is not explicitly defined in the `interface ISideProps` and as such TS is refusing to compile, even though, everything in JSX has a goddamn className

Comment: Updated my post. Is this the answer you were looking for?

Comment: I struggled with this too at the very beginning. :) TypeScript is documented poorly in react.

Answer (score 1):

> All i want is to be able to define a typscript interface for my component and have it extend the default interface any component uses

In this case you can define a DefaultProps interface and then use it to extend any Component Props:

```
interface DefaultProps {
    onClick?: Function;
    className?:string;
}

interface ISideProps extends DefaultProps {
    wideModeEnabled: boolean;
    // ...
}
```

This needs to be done for custom Components which, by default, do not expect to receive any prop.

On the other hand, built-in components like `<div>` or `<span>` have already defined the props that correspond to their HTML elements. An `<img>` for example, will have an `src` prop defined.

In order to use those predefined interfaces, you can make use of them from the React module, as [@oemera suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924229).

Comment: Is it there really no way to circumevent actually defining default props. Can't I just extend something react uses internally for Functional components, or rather, any component for that matter. Is there even such a thing. If I really need to define every single prop I am baffled, just the eventHandlers are like upwards of a 100... it would also defeat the whole purpose of intellisense when I get barraged with over a hundred default things that are not specific to this particular interface.

Comment: You don't need to write your own interface, use the in-built react interface instead : `interface ISideProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>`

Comment: @Dellirium. Well, you need to define them if you are going to use them. Passing `onClick` to a `<div>` doesnt need to be defined, but passing it to a Component, for example `<MyDiv>`, needs to be defined. Also as @oemera suggests you can use the predefined interfaces from React.

Comment: Yeh i wanted to somehow be able to extend this feature of passing onClick to a div, because to me, a person that can't stand typscript, it is absurd that I have to define it . But in accordance to oemera's suggestion, extending works fine. Thanks to both of you

Comment: @Dellirium Im glad you could solve. TypeScript can be tricky sometimes. Ill extend the answer to make it more complete.